# Meteor: find by full name (multiple fields)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm implementing persons list inside my Meteor app. Every person has a lastName and firstName. I want to be able to search by full name or it's part. Of course search must be case insensitive. There will be about 500 persons, so I need pagination & I can't just filter the results on client side.

My general idea is to generate additional field fullName upon insert or update of a person:

```js
fullName: lastName.toLowerCase() + ' ' + firstName.toLowerCase(),
```

And then just use it inside the find method:

```js
PersonsCollection.find({ fullName: {$regex : searchString}, ... })
```

I'm pretty new to Meteor, Mongo and backend in general. I spent some time researching, but still  confused. My questions are:

- Is there any real reasons against my implementation besides it's kinda ugly to create additional field?
- Is there a conventional way to do this in Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

It is usual to create an additional field.

But you can try to use an $or:

```
PersonsCollection.find(
  { 
    $or: [ 
      { firstName: new RegExp(searchString, 'i') },
      { lastName: new RegExp(searchString, 'i') } 
    ] 
  }
);
```

Don't forgot to create indexes to your search fields.

Comment: Thank you!
Additional field suits me well, and $or doesn't help with the full name query (i.e. "John Smith").